# How to set dash display brightness in Renault Clio 2017

Tags: renault, dashboard, clio

I have a rental car with interesting problem. It is a Renault Clio made in 2017.
On the dash there is only a digital display showing speed, there is no dial. The problem is the display brightness is very dim if the headlights are turned on. If I switch the lights off the display gets brighter. The result is that I cannot see the speed at all because of the sunlight.

Is there any way to set the display brighter?

Comment: Switch off the headlights and use the daytime running lights. If they aren't already on, there should be a system setting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about 2017 Clio, but older ones had a little thumbwheel to adjust the brightness. It should be on dash left from your steering wheel.